# How to retrieve a variable from a downstream project in Gitlabci

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

so here's my problem.
I have a project that needs to trigger a pipeline to another project.
During this call, I need to pass a variable between the two projects.

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  allow_failure: true
  when: manual
  script :
    - VERSION_PROJECT=v1.8.0
    - echo "VERSION_PROJECT=$VERSION_PROJECT" >> publish.env 
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: publish.env

job_to_downstream:
  stage: stage1
  allow_failure: true
  needs: ["job1"]
  trigger:
    project: path/to/project
    branch: branch1
    strategy: depend
  variables:
    ENV: dev
    VERSION: ${VERSION_PROJECT}
```

When I do this to route the variable to the downstream project, everything works. I just have to export the variable in a script (export VERSION_PROJECT="${VERSION}";) and it comes back as it should. On this new project, I calculate a new variable.
But when I want to run a pipeline on the upstream project, I can't get this new variable.

```
job_downstream:
  stage: downstreamjob
  script :
    - source ./bash/somescript.sh;
    - echo "STATIC_URL=$STATIC_URL" >> publish.env;
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: publish.env

job_upstream_url:
  stage: url
  script :
    - export STATIC_URL="${STATIC_URL}";
    - echo "$STATIC_URL";
  needs:
    - job: job_to_downstream
      artifacts: true
```

The static_url variable is empty. I've been flipping the code back and forth but I'm really stuck on this point.
I tried with or without the artifact true, without the needs ... nothing works.
Do you have an idea to transfer the environment variables from downstream project to upstream? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If your "somescript" does not set the value of STATIC_URL then there is no way this would not be empty. What does the script do? Where does the content of STATIC_URL should come from. For tests, just replace `echo "STATIC_URL=$STATIC_URL" >> publish.env;` with `echo "STATIC_URL=testtest" >> publish.env;` and see if this works.

Comment: "somescript" calculates a url, at the end of the script I do an echo of the variable and it is well returned.
As you rightly suggested, I replaced the variable called by ""STATIC_URL=testtest"".
The result is the same, the variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own problem.
The solution for me was to use a need in the stage, like that :

```
job_upstream_url:
  stage: url
  script :
    - export STATIC_URL="${STATIC_URL}";
    - echo "$STATIC_URL";
  needs:
    - project : projectURL
      job: nameofTheJobInProjectURL
      ref: branch
          artifacts: true
```

With this block, I can access to artefacts

Answer (score 0):

One solution: add `source publish.env` as first command in your script.